# Accessing Dict in a list in a list

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I'm dealing with some JSON and parsing it in Python I have this one part I can't seem to figure out the syntax for. So here's my JSON:

```
u'line_items':[  
     {  
        u'product':{  
           u'weight':0.5,
           u'regular_price':u'$40.00',
           u'name_short':u'Name',
           u'currency':u'USD',
           },
     {  
        u'product':{  
           u'weight':None,
           u'regular_price':u'$17.00',
           u'name_short':u'Map of the World Jumbo Puzzle',
           u'currency':u'USD',
     }
  ]
```

And sometimes there are more than one product in the line_items list. What is the syntax to iterate through the product dicts in line_items? I'm trying

```
for j in i['line_items']
  product = j['product']
```

but it only works for the first product. Also, `i` serves as an enumerator for a larger dict that includes `line_items`.

Comment: `i['line_items']` is a list, not a dictionary, you want e.g. `for d in i['line_items']: for whatever in d['product']:` (note no `s`) to get the keys in the innermost dictionary.

Comment: You've given us invalid syntax (u'line_items': is inside something else that you are not telling us about). If you give us a short, working program we are more likely to be able to answer it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't given us the full data structure I am only guessing , but, ... you only have one level of lists. Enumerate it to get the product dicts.

```
for item in i['line_items']:
    product = item['product']
    weight = product['weight']
    # sanity check
    print("product: %s, weight: %s" % (product['name_short'], weight))
```

Comment: So this is only working for the first product in line_items, see edit.

Comment: @kat - I think it will work for all. In your example, `line_items` is a list of dicts. the `for` loop iterates through that list of dicts, executing the body for each one.

Answer (score -1):

Iterate over products:

```
for product in i['line_items']:
    # prints single products
    print product
```

Or if you need the product index (for `index_in_list` in following examples):

```
for index_in_list in range(len(i['line_items'])):
    # prints single products
    print i['line_items'][index_in_list]
```

---

Iterate over a single product's keys:

```
for product_key in i['line_items'][index_in_list]:
    # prints product info
    print product_key, '-', i['line_items']['product'][product_key]
```

Or easier:

```
for product_key, product in i['line_items'][index_in_list].iteritems():
    # still has access to 'product_key' if you want to modify it.
    print product_key, '-', product
```

Comment: `i['line_items']` **is a list**, so this is a `TypeError`.